AWS ELB sticky session cookie rejected
So i have developing a application that uses socket.io. I have containerized this application and used it on aws ecs with a application load balancer infront of them to load balance the request.
Now when i try to make a connection i get error about not being able to make a connection with them. I figured it must be due to load balancer sending connection request to other container so socket.io connection is not forming. I come to this conclusion because when there is only one container on ecs service i can connect with it without any problem.
So i used sticky session to send requests from user to same container but this is the problem i am getting.
Cookie “AWSALB” will soon be rejected because it is foreign and does not have the “Partitioned“ attribute.
Is there way to handle this as i cannot configure the cookie send by application load balancer.
I have read this post. This is about albcors etc but i didn't get it also original post is not available now so i am not sure about this.

